# Split an equation of matrix

Tags: split

Could anyone guide me on how to split an equation of matrix?

[image]

I have tried this code but the functions of delimiter '&' are intercepted (functions of split and matrix)

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\[
a&=\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&3&4\\
5&6&7&8\\
\end{bmatrix}&=66
\]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Thank you

Comment: You should probably read a proper intro for math in LaTeX as you are make many mistakes. Remove `\[` and `\]` , insert a ``\\`` before `&=66` and you should be done.

Comment: Thank you so much , Mr Daleif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

- please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example)
- your code fragment is quite strange, correct MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a &=\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&3&4\\
5&6&7&8\\
\end{bmatrix}   \\  % <----
&=66
\end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]